# Access control of linked file/folder on server

Tags: html, apache, authentication

I have access to a server ( as a user) with very basic features to create a simple webpage. No scripting languages (php etc) are allowed or supported. I wanted to create a profile page with linkes to few documents and source code. The doc and source should be only accessible to people with some login/password (authentication) on my page. I want to do this such that I can keep track of users who is interested in the work. How can I do this using only HTML ?  If I were to have complete access to the system ( that is running Apache webserver with MySQL to host the webpages), what could be the easiest way to setup an access control on any files/folders?

Comment: This isn't a mysql question, I suggest removing the tag.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I do this using only HTML ?

You can't.

> If I were to have complete access to the system ( that is running Apache webserver with MySQL to host the webpages), what could be the easiest way to setup an access control on any files/folders?

Apache's [built-in access control](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/auth.html) options.